# Decode / summarise strace logs

Tags: strace

OK, so it's no secret that `strace` produces *vast* amounts of output. (I'm aware there are various options to filter the output a bit.)

Are there any tools to process a raw `strace` log into something more human-readable?

What kind of "decoding" am I looking for? Well, by design `strace` works at a very low level. I'm looking for something that can summarize the most important points. For example, FD 4 might point to different files at different instants; it would be useful to have *the machine* keep track of this, rather than me. Ditto for PIDs. I would like to be able to see process trees at different moments in the trace, and so forth. A GUI tool would be great, but even something text-based would be acceptable if it makes things a bit easier to follow.

Comment: Note that if you pass `strace` the `-y` flag, it will automatically label all FDs with what they're pointing to. Still doesn't help for PIDs and the like, but helpful none the less!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Summary while strace runs

`strace` has the `-c` switch which will give you a summary report of the various system calls that were made.

*excerpt strace man page*

```
-c      Count time, calls, and errors for each system call and report a 
        summary on program exit.  On Linux, this attempts to show system 
        time (CPU  time  spent  running in the kernel) independent of wall 
        clock time.  If -c is used with -f or -F (below), only aggregate 
        totals for all traced processes are kept.
```

#### Example

```
$ strace -c systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
...
...
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 51.81    0.001831        1831         1           waitid
  8.15    0.000288           7        39           mmap
  7.89    0.000279          19        15           read
  6.11    0.000216           8        26           mprotect
  4.56    0.000161          11        15           open
  2.91    0.000103         103         1           connect
  2.24    0.000079          79         1           clone
  2.15    0.000076          38         2           statfs
  2.01    0.000071           4        19           close
  1.95    0.000069           5        13           poll
  1.90    0.000067           5        14         2 recvmsg
  1.70    0.000060           4        16           fstat
  0.88    0.000031           8         4         3 stat
  0.82    0.000029          29         1           socket
  0.65    0.000023           8         3           munmap
  0.57    0.000020           5         4           sendto
  0.42    0.000015           5         3           ioctl
  0.40    0.000014           7         2           lstat
  0.40    0.000014           7         2           sendmsg
  0.34    0.000012           4         3           brk
  0.23    0.000008           8         1           pipe
  0.23    0.000008           4         2           fcntl
  0.20    0.000007           4         2           rt_sigaction
  0.20    0.000007           7         1         1 access
  0.20    0.000007           4         2           geteuid
  0.17    0.000006           6         1           execve
  0.14    0.000005           5         1           getsockname
  0.11    0.000004           4         1           dup2
  0.11    0.000004           4         1           getresuid
  0.11    0.000004           4         1           getresgid
  0.11    0.000004           4         1           arch_prctl
  0.08    0.000003           3         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.08    0.000003           3         1           getrlimit
  0.08    0.000003           3         1           set_tid_address
  0.08    0.000003           3         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           kill
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.003534                   207         6 total
```

#### Analyzing strace logs postmortem

I found this Perl scripts called [`Strace_analyzer.pl`](https://clusterbuffer.wordpress.com/strace-analyzer/) which sounds like what you're looking for.

*Usage*

```
$ ./strace_analyzer_ng_0.03.pl -help
Usage: strace-analyze [OPTION]… [FILE]
Analyzes strace output for IO functions. It creates statistics
on IO functions and performance of the read and write functions.
The strace file should have been run with ‘strace -tt [PROGRAM]
```

There's an example of the output on the page I linked to above. It's too long to post here. I've posted here on pastebin.com as well.

- [Strace_Analyzer.pl sample output](http://pastebin.com/XreLHQae)
- [IO Profiling of Applications: strace_analyzer - Linux Magazine article](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7730/)

#### Alternative to strace, ioapps

I came across this app called [`ioapps`](https://code.google.com/p/ioapps/wiki/IOProfilerScreenshots) which can give you a more visual breakdown of what your app is doing when it's running. Perhaps this might be better for what you're trying to accomplish than processing `strace` logs.

*Usage*

> ```
>   $ ioprofiler-trace thunderbird
> ```
>
> Once it loads, we just close the thunderbird window and check we have
>   a trace log called "ioproftrace.log" because that's the default name
>   of the log (one can specify another name using -o command line
>   option):
>
> ```
>   $ ls -l ioproftrace.log 
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 74890554 Apr  4 22:04 ioproftrace.log
> ```
>
> It seems OK, so we can run ioprofiler over it:
>
> ```
>   $ ioprofiler ioproftrace.log
> ```

*Example GUI*

[image: ss1]

#### Another alternative to strace, strace+

**NOTE:** The project, [strace+](https://code.google.com/p/strace-plus/), is no longer being maintained, and in fact many of its features have been merged into the default `strace` via the `-k` switch. So you might want to make sure your version of `strace` is at least up to 4.9, which is when that switch was merged in.

*excerpt strace man page*

```
-k          Print the execution stack trace of the traced processes after 
            each system call (experimental).
```

*excerpt from strace+ project page*

> strace+ is an improved version of strace that collects stack traces
>   associated with each system call. Since system calls require an
>   expensive user-kernel context switch, they are often sources of
>   performance bottlenecks. strace+ allows programmers to do more
>   detailed system call profiling and determine, say, which call sites
>   led to costly syscalls and thus have potential for optimization.

Comment: None of these does precisely what I'm after, but it's all useful information none the less.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid - yeah I know, I looked for a bit and couldn't find anything that did exactly what you listed in your requirements in the Q.

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me that couldn't find much... :-)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid - 8-). BTW if you go to github.com and search for strace you can find a lot more projects than what I listed here. Some of them look like they might be half way decent leads. https://github.com/search?p=1&q=strace&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93